# what type is filterCriteria.filterOperation?

Tags: onem2m

TS-0004 table 6.3.5.8-1 has:

```
filterOperation | m2m:filterOperation | 0..1 |
```

but CDT-commonTypes-v2_7_0.xsd has:

```
<xs:complexType name="filterCriteria">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="filterOperation" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
```

which is correct?

Answer (score 0):

TS-0004 is the normative reference. The definition of *m2m:filterOperation* in the latest version of TS-0004 (v4.0.0) does also define an XOR operation (value = 3), so a boolean would not be sufficient.

Normally, for each version of the spec document there is a matching XSD. For release 4 there will be a new XSD.